# gitweb 404 - No projects found

Tags: apache, gitweb

I want to use gitweb with apache server,but when i finish config it.i request gitweb and there is always a `404 - No projects found`.

My git repository is `/home/git/repo` and
I change `/etc/gitweb.conf` with `$projectroot = "/var/www/git";` and change `/etc/httpd/conf.d/git.conf` with

```
Alias /git /var/www/git
<Directory /var/www/git>
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
    SetEnv GITWEB_CONFIG /etc/gitweb.conf
    Dav On
    RewriteEngine Off
</Directory>
```

Then run `ln -s /home/git/repo/test_repo.git /var/www/git/` to make a shortcut in `/var/www/git`.but I can't get what I want.

Comment: Your folder is repo or repositorie ? And did you check that gitweb got all permissions needed to look in /home/git/repo directory ?

Comment: My folder is `repo` and the command should be `ln -s /home/git/repo/test_repo.git /var/www/git/`,I had written it wrong And Could you tell me how to make gitweb get permissions needed,Thanks!